# Fail all other gestures

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

In my container controller, sometimes I have to add a gesture recognizer to a view to handle things. Is it possible to fail all the other gestures on said view and only execute the added gesture?

**Option 1:**
Right now, all the individual gestures are set to fail when the new gesture has been detected, but it doesn't seem very efficient to do it this way.

**Option 2:**
Another way is get the array of gestures of said view and set `enabled` to `false` for all the gestures inside the array.

What I'd like to do is set the delegate of the new gesture to the container controller and use one of the delegate methods to fail all other gestures when the new gesture has been detected.

Comment: May be you can disable user interaction for those view...and make your gesture to work

Comment: That would work, since the new gesture is in another view. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove other gesture recogniser and want keep one gesture which user used then you can do by detecting the direction of that gesture and then you can remove all other gestures and you can keep used gesture.

Here is complete working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("rightSwiped:"))
        swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("leftSwiped:"))
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("downSwiped:"))
        swipeDown.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("upSwiped:"))
        swipeUp.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    }

    func rightSwiped(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("right swiped ")
        manageGesture(recognizer)

    }

    func manageGesture(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

        //First detect which gesture is used

        if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right {
            println("Right")

            if let recognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
                for recognizer in recognizers {
                    if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right {
                        println("Called")
                    }else {
                        view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as! UIGestureRecognizer)
                    }
                }
            }

        }else if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left {
            println("Left")

            if let recognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
                for recognizer in recognizers {
                    if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left {
                        println("Called")
                    }else {
                        view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as! UIGestureRecognizer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up {
            println("Up")

            if let recognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
                for recognizer in recognizers {
                    if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up {
                        println("Called")
                    }else {
                        view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as! UIGestureRecognizer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }else if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down {
            println("Down")

            if let recognizers = view.gestureRecognizers {
                for recognizer in recognizers {
                    if recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down {
                        println("Called")
                    }else {
                        view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer as! UIGestureRecognizer)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    func leftSwiped(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("left swiped ")
        manageGesture(recognizer)
    }

    func downSwiped(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("down swiped ")
        manageGesture(recognizer)
    }

    func upSwiped(recognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer)
    {
        println("Up swiped ")
        manageGesture(recognizer)
    }


}
```

Hope this is what you need.